# Org-mode C-u C-c C-c fail to add checkboxes to the rest of the list

Tags: org-mode

the original content like this:

```
* TODO My list
  - list
    - sub-list A
    - sub-list B
    - sub-list C
```

after I have typed C-u C-c C-c at the position "- list", the content like this:

```
* TODO My list
  - [ ] list
    - sub-list A
    - sub-list B
    - sub-list C
```

it does not work as my expected:

```
* TODO My list
  - [ ] list
    - [ ] sub-list A
    - [ ] sub-list B
    - [ ] sub-list C
```

the documention is state that " C-u C-c C-c  on the *first* item of a list with no checkbox will add checkboxes to the rest of the list."

Is there anything wrong or my misunderstanding?

Answer (score 2):

This answer is valid for `org-version` 9.1.6.

The [documentation](https://orgmode.org/manual/Checkboxes.html#DOCF56) says something slightly different:

> C-u C-c C-c before the first bullet in a list with no checkbox will add checkboxes to the rest of the list.

It says `before` and not `on`.

Furthermore, the adding of checkboxes does not work for the sub-list but for the list itself.

Consider an org file with the following content:

```
* TODO My list
  - first item
    - sub-list item 1A
    - sub-list item 1B
  - second item
    - sub-list item 2A
    - sub-list item 2B
```

If you go to the beginning of the line with `first item` and hit <kbd>C-u C-c C-c</kbd> you get:

```
* TODO My list
  - [ ] first item
    - sub-list item 1A
    - sub-list item 1B
  - [ ] second item
    - sub-list item 2A
    - sub-list item 2B
```

You can also go to the beginning of the line with `sub-list item 1A` and hit <kbd>C-u C-c C-c</kbd> to add checkboxes to the first sub-list.

Comment: I just don't understand why there is plural for the word checkbox, for one  list, there is only one checkbox after you hit C-u C-c C-c, I get much confused. My org-mode version is 8.2.10, the footnote part of the info manual(5.6 Checkboxes) says the same as my question statement. I guess that C-u C-c C-c have no effect of adding checkboxes to all the sub-list, does any command could work for this?